# Ruby - passing by value or by reference

Tags: ruby

I've searched on this, and everyone seems to say Ruby always passes by value, but this simple little example is a subset of a much larger program, and I'm a little confused.

```
a = "J123"
b = a
a.slice!(0)
puts a
puts b
```

This displays

```
123
123
```

And I don't understand why the value of "b" is changing.

Comment: Use `b = a.dup` to allow deep copy of content. Then `b` will not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both `a` and `b` are pointers that refer to the same object. They aren't the object itself. You can only pass pointers as arguments in Ruby, and pointers are passed by value.

This is similar to Java, JavaScript and Python, and unlike C++, C#, Haskell and Scala.

The difference is of interest in the following example:

```
def f(y)
  y = 2
end
x = 1
f(x)
puts x # 1, not 2
```

If `x` were passed by reference, it would print `2`.

Comment: Ugh.  I understand what you're describing, but how can I make an immutable copy of the contents of a variable?

Comment: @JRQ Strings in Ruby are always mutable, so you cannot. You can clone strings by sending `dup` or `clone` to them, like `b = a.dup`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I can see that this is mainly a string "issue"

Comment: C# also works like this by default for reference types. C# has both reference and value types and both pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, but the "default" (i.e. no use of the `ref` keyword and an instance of a `class` rather than a `struct`) mode is the same as Ruby. Scala's is the same as Java, except that it also supports call-by-name for individual parameters. Haskell is pure, so the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference actually cannot be observed, so you simply don't know which of the two it is (and in fact, compilers use both depending on what is faster).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am fully aware of all of those, was talking about languages which have only pass-by-value. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is pass by value. Everything in ruby is an object. Meaning all variables are actually references(pointers) to that item somewhere in memory.

```
x = 5 # (5 is stored as object in mem location 0x0001)
y = x # (now y also points to mem location 0x0001)
```

When you pass your variable into a function and it copies that variable by value - **it is copying the memory location address, not the actual object at that memory location**.

In your example, both a and b's values (memory locations) were copied by value. However they point to the same memory location, so modifying that location in memory through one variable still modifies the value of the other.

**EDIT:**

There is a [great write-up here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm?repost) (for Java which is also pass-by-value), about how to test whether a language truly supports pass-by-reference.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was getting confused. If I did a similar test using integers, such as a=2, b=a, a=a*2.  The value of a is 4, and the value of b is still 2, which is what I was anticipating with strings.

Comment: That's because with `a=a*2` you are re-assigning `a` to point to another location. Strings work the same way (a string and int are both objects in Ruby!). Use the following to make your string code analogous to your int code: `a = a.slice(0)` - there is a big difference between `slice!` and `slice`

Comment: Point well taken.  Thanks again.